# Error installing composer in windows PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\json.so'

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I get this error while installing composer in Windows.

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\json.so' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove this line from php.ini , this was the problem

```
extension=json.so
```

Comment: On Linux, extensions are shared object files, e.g. .so files. On Windows, extensions are usually .dll files. So yes, removing that line was likely correct, but it's interesting that you had this in your .ini in the first place.